# What is the solution of the integral equation $y(x)-\lambda\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert \sin(x) y(t)dt =x$?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> The solution of the integral equation
> $y(x)-\lambda\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert \sin(x) y(t)dt =x$ is
>
> $(1)y(x)=x-\lambda\pi^3\sin(x)$
>
> $(2)y(x)=x+\lambda\pi^3\sin(x)$
>
> $(3)y(x)=x+\lambda\pi^3\cot(x)$
>
> $(4)y(x)=x+\lambda\pi^2\sin(x)$

$y(x)=x+\lambda\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert \sin(x) y(t)dt $

$y(x)=x+\lambda\sin(x)\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert  y(t)dt\tag{1} $

$let,C=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert  y(t)dt\tag{2}$

So,equation $(1)$ becomes $y(x)=x+\lambda C\sin(x)\implies y(t)=t+\lambda C\sin(t)$.

Putting $y(t)=t+\lambda C\sin(t)$ in equation $(2),$ we get

$C=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert  (t+\lambda C\sin(t))dt$

$\implies C=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert  tdt+\lambda C\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert  \sin(t))dt$

$\implies C=\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-t)  tdt-\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert  tdt+\lambda C\int_{0}^{2\pi}\vert\pi-t\vert  \sin(t))dt$

$\implies C=\int_{0}^{\pi}(\pi-t)  tdt-\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}(\pi-t)  tdt+\lambda C\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\pi-t)  \sin(t))dt$

$\implies C=[\frac{\pi t^2}{2}-\frac{ t^3}{3}]_{0}^{\pi}-[\frac{\pi t^2}{2}-\frac{ t^3}{3}]_{\pi}^{2\pi}+\lambda C[(t-\pi)\cos(t)-\sin(t)]_{0}^{2\pi}$

$\implies C=[\frac{\pi^3 }{2}-\frac{ \pi^3}{3}]-[\frac{4\pi^3}{2}-\frac{ 8\pi^3}{3}-\frac{\pi^3}{2}+\frac{\pi^3}{3}]+\lambda C[(2\pi-\pi)(1)+\pi]$

$\implies C=\pi^3+2\lambda C \pi$

$\implies C=\frac{\pi^3}{1-2\pi \lambda}$.

Putting the value of $C$ in $y(x)=x+\lambda C\sin(x)$,we get $y(x)=x+\lambda \frac{\pi^3}{1-2\pi \lambda}\sin(x)$.

**Please check my solution,where I did wrong?**

Is there any alternative way for the above problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your last integral

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} |\pi-t|\sin t dt$$
Use $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx=\int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) dx$
$$I=-\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\pi -t| \sin t dt$$
$$\implies 2I=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} |\pi-t|\sin(t) dt = \int_0^{\pi} (\pi-t)\sin(t) dt + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi} -(\pi-t)\sin(t) dt$$
$$=\pi \int_0^{\pi}\sin(t)dt - \int_0^{\pi}t\sin(t)dt -\pi \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\sin(t)dt + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}t\sin(t)dt$$

$$=4\pi - \int_0^{\pi}t\sin(t)dt + \int_{\pi}^{2\pi}t\sin(t)dt$$
and

$$\int_0^{\pi}t\sin(t)dt = \pi$$
$$\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}t\sin(t) = -3\pi$$

therefore $\int_0^{2\pi} |\pi-t|\sin(t) dt = 0$ and $C=\pi^3$ only.

On the other hand, the method you used is the most straightforward method for a separable kernel of the form $a(x)b(t)$.